# Custom search box which searches through document libraries on all subsites

Tags: web-part, document-library, search, search-results, content-and-structure

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly simple, but after countless hours of Googling I cannot come up with a solution.

Basically I want to have a search box on my top level site, which allows the user to search through all of the document libraries on all of the sub-sites of my root site. I'm using the online version of sharepoint.com (Office365)

My structure is as follows:

```
root (search box will be here)
|--SubSite1
| |--Document Library 1
| |--Document Library 2
| |--Documebt Library 3
|--SubSite2
| |--Document Library 4
| |--Document Library 5
|--SubSite3
| |--Document Library 6
| |--Document Library 7
| |--Document Library 8
| |--Document Library 9
|--SubSite4
| |--Document Library 10
| |--Document Library 11
```

... et cetera. I think in total there will be about +- 100 subsites, and an average of 5 document libraries per subsite.

The idea of the root site search is just to provide the user with a quick "catch-all" search through all of the available documents.

Is this possible at all with the Search and Search Result Web Parts? I feel like this is kind of a basic requirement so it should be do-able to create it without doing anything fancy, but after not having found any good information I'm starting to feel a bit lost. :)

Answer (score 1):

By Default search should bring you results across all Sites (the users has Access to). Or you did somehow scoped the results to current Site

Comment: Interesting. I didn't change anything. I just signed up for a trial account ate Sharepoint.com and started experimenting there. EDIT: even if I use the default search on a sub site to search for a filename it does not return anything. Maybe I need to set some setting to include document library files in search results? For example searching for Document Library names or folder names inside the Document Library seems to work.

Comment: I guess it does seem to work but it needs about 15 minutes to be updated due to the search crawl setup.